# How to Diagnose this hepatitis A, B and C case?

Tags: microbiology, homework, hepatitis

Male patient who is working in the hospital and may be infected with contaminated blood had hepatitis
with genome IA 5 years ago. His hepatitis A at that time was confirmed with the rise of anti.HAV IgM and
later with anti-­HAV IgG type antibodies. His wife is known to have antibodies against C hepatitits. The
patient had icteric illness in about three weeks ago. Which are the best indicators in
diagnosing his hepatitis?

Right answer is: Detection of HBsAg and anti-HCV antibodies.

I think this is because

- to check if he has hepatitis B by HBsAg
- to check if he has HepC by the antibody

Serum antigen of HB tells us about the levels of IgM and IgG. 
If vaccinated, then IgG should be positive, I think?
**What does HBsAg tell you?**

**Why do we need to detect anti-HCV?
If they are found, what does it mean?** 
I think that then it means if found that he does not have hepatitis C then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last sentence of the question doesn't make it clear what's being asked. But it seems to be asking: `What version of Hepatitis did he get from the contaminated blood?`

To that end...

> Serum antigen of HB tells us about the levels of IgM and IgG. If vaccinated, then IgG should be positive, I think? What does HBsAg tell you?

HBsAg gives you the knowledge of whether or not there's an acute infection of Hep-B. [Hep-B IgM antibodies indicate an *acute* infection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepatitis#Diagnosis), whilst IgG antibodies would show up due to his previous exposure/immunization. If the patient has Hep-B IgM, the icteric illness was probably a re-infection of Hep-B.

> Why do we need to detect anti-HCV? If they are found, what does it mean? I think that then it means if found that he does not have hepatitis C then.

That would my assumption as well.

You run the HBsAg and can get two outcomes: IgM(+)/IgG(+) or IgM(-)/IgG(+). The former indicates the icteric illness was probably a reinfection of Hep-B.

You run the anti-HCV and get two outcomes: (+) or (-). The former indicates a present infection, the latter indicates no Hep-C.

What might throw you off is the wife's anti-HepC antibodies. If she was formerly infected and infected the patient (or vice versa) then you'd *expect* to find a (+) anti-HCV result.

I might come back to this after thinking on it a bit more, but that's the best I have for now.